Reuse a line or a block of text without creating dummy code
In Doxygen, how to reuse a line or a block of text?
Suppose I write the following in some file:
/**
 * \magicCommand{magicLabel}{this is some text that I want to show.}
 */

Then, when I write the following in another file,
/**
 * OK, \someRefFun{magicLabel}
 */
void f() {}

Doxygen will create the following in the html document for f():
OK, this is some text that I want to show.
I see @copydoc can do something like this, but the problem is that I would
need to create some dummy function for the referred text to depend on. Can
it be done without using a dummy function?

Which version of doxygen are you using? You already mentioned @copydoc but probably here the use of @snippet{doc} might be more appropriate.
